# Link/share Macros between Access files

Tags: vba, microsoft-access

I have several accdb files.
Most of them (I will call them slaves) have only tables and queries and only one (I will call it master) have vba macros that actuate over the other files as an engine.

Now I need to use directly on an 'slave' file a macro stored on the 'master' file, but I don't want to duplicate it because if I make some change on the vba code in the master, I will need also to replicate the same change on the 'slave' code.

It is possible to link tables between accdb files. It is also possible to link queries between accdb files (using full path on the SQL statement)

My question is: is there any possibility to link a vba macro code from an access file to another access file similarly as the import table manager or 'absolute path' query SQL statement?

Comment: when I talk about the "link query" I mean that it is possible to link a query from other access into the current access without liking also the origin tables. Example: SELECT * FROM [C:\Users\username\Desktop\Database.accdb].Query1

Comment: Create new module (or open some existing) in "slave" database. Then Tools-References, find "master" database (via Browse knob) and add it. Now you can use public subs/funcs from "master" database in "slave" code.

Comment: For about 1 minute I thought that you gave me the answer hahaha, but the problem is that when I close and open again the 'slave' file, the Reference to the 'master' is not there anymore and is needed to re-load again the Reference. Is it possible to left it there forever?

Comment: *when I close and open again the 'slave' file, the Reference to the 'master' is not there anymore and is needed to re-load again the Reference.* I cannot reproduce this behavior...

Comment: STEP BY STEP: 1º open 'slave' file. 2º load the 'master' code through Tools-References. 3º close 'slave' file. 4º open again 'slave' file --> the 'master' code is unloaded and to use it I have to do again the step 2

Comment: *load the 'master' code through Tools-References* In VBA Editor while some common module active? *the 'master' code is unloaded* Does reference to it dissapeares from references list? or it presents, but is marked as unavailable/wrong/absent? Do you see the 'master' database in Project pane when joined and after close/reopen?

Comment: Ok. Now i got it. The problem was that the Project name in both files was the same. I have modified the 'master' project name and now it works!!! Thank you @Akina!!! Now I need you to write an answer so I can put this question as SOLVED

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Create new module (or open some existing) in "slave" database VBA Editor.
- Tools-References, find "master" database (via Browse knob) and add it.
- Use public subs/funcs from "master" database in "slave" code.

Avoid of names interferences (project, module, sub/function, variable...).